# How to cluster similar sentences using BERT

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, word-embedding, bert-language-model

For ElMo, FastText and Word2Vec, I'm averaging the word embeddings within a sentence and using HDBSCAN/KMeans clustering to group similar sentences.

A good example of the implementation can be seen in this short article: http://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/text-clustering-word-embedding-machine-learning/

I would like to do the same thing using BERT (using the BERT python package from hugging face), however I am rather unfamiliar with how to extract the raw word/sentence vectors in order to input them into a clustering algorithm. I know that BERT can output sentence representations - so how would I actually extract the raw vectors from a sentence?

Any information would be helpful.

Comment: Don't use BERT for this, it was never trained for the semantic similarity objective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Subham Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4935974/subham-kumar) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62859000/395857), one can use this Python 3 library to compute sentence similarity: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers

The library has a few [code examples](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/tree/master/examples/applications/clustering) to perform clustering:

[`fast_clustering.py`](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/applications/clustering/fast_clustering.py):

```
"""
This is a more complex example on performing clustering on large scale dataset.

This examples find in a large set of sentences local communities, i.e., groups of sentences that are highly
similar. You can freely configure the threshold what is considered as similar. A high threshold will
only find extremely similar sentences, a lower threshold will find more sentence that are less similar.

A second parameter is 'min_community_size': Only communities with at least a certain number of sentences will be returned.

The method for finding the communities is extremely fast, for clustering 50k sentences it requires only 5 seconds (plus embedding comuptation).

In this example, we download a large set of questions from Quora and then find similar questions in this set.
"""
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import os
import csv
import time


# Model for computing sentence embeddings. We use one trained for similar questions detection
model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

# We donwload the Quora Duplicate Questions Dataset (https://www.quora.com/q/quoradata/First-Quora-Dataset-Release-Question-Pairs)
# and find similar question in it
url = "http://qim.fs.quoracdn.net/quora_duplicate_questions.tsv"
dataset_path = "quora_duplicate_questions.tsv"
max_corpus_size = 50000 # We limit our corpus to only the first 50k questions


# Check if the dataset exists. If not, download and extract
# Download dataset if needed
if not os.path.exists(dataset_path):
    print("Download dataset")
    util.http_get(url, dataset_path)

# Get all unique sentences from the file
corpus_sentences = set()
with open(dataset_path, encoding='utf8') as fIn:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fIn, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        corpus_sentences.add(row['question1'])
        corpus_sentences.add(row['question2'])
        if len(corpus_sentences) >= max_corpus_size:
            break

corpus_sentences = list(corpus_sentences)
print("Encode the corpus. This might take a while")
corpus_embeddings = model.encode(corpus_sentences, batch_size=64, show_progress_bar=True, convert_to_tensor=True)


print("Start clustering")
start_time = time.time()

#Two parameters to tune:
#min_cluster_size: Only consider cluster that have at least 25 elements
#threshold: Consider sentence pairs with a cosine-similarity larger than threshold as similar
clusters = util.community_detection(corpus_embeddings, min_community_size=25, threshold=0.75)

print("Clustering done after {:.2f} sec".format(time.time() - start_time))

#Print for all clusters the top 3 and bottom 3 elements
for i, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
    print("\nCluster {}, #{} Elements ".format(i+1, len(cluster)))
    for sentence_id in cluster[0:3]:
        print("\t", corpus_sentences[sentence_id])
    print("\t", "...")
    for sentence_id in cluster[-3:]:
        print("\t", corpus_sentences[sentence_id])
```

[`kmeans.py`](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/applications/clustering/kmeans.py):

```
"""
This is a simple application for sentence embeddings: clustering

Sentences are mapped to sentence embeddings and then k-mean clustering is applied.
"""
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

# Corpus with example sentences
corpus = ['A man is eating food.',
          'A man is eating a piece of bread.',
          'A man is eating pasta.',
          'The girl is carrying a baby.',
          'The baby is carried by the woman',
          'A man is riding a horse.',
          'A man is riding a white horse on an enclosed ground.',
          'A monkey is playing drums.',
          'Someone in a gorilla costume is playing a set of drums.',
          'A cheetah is running behind its prey.',
          'A cheetah chases prey on across a field.'
          ]
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus)

# Perform kmean clustering
num_clusters = 5
clustering_model = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
clustering_model.fit(corpus_embeddings)
cluster_assignment = clustering_model.labels_

clustered_sentences = [[] for i in range(num_clusters)]
for sentence_id, cluster_id in enumerate(cluster_assignment):
    clustered_sentences[cluster_id].append(corpus[sentence_id])

for i, cluster in enumerate(clustered_sentences):
    print("Cluster ", i+1)
    print(cluster)
    print("")
```

[`agglomerative.py`](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/applications/clustering/agglomerative.py):

```
"""
This is a simple application for sentence embeddings: clustering

Sentences are mapped to sentence embeddings and then agglomerative clustering with a threshold is applied.
"""
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import numpy as np

embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

# Corpus with example sentences
corpus = ['A man is eating food.',
          'A man is eating a piece of bread.',
          'A man is eating pasta.',
          'The girl is carrying a baby.',
          'The baby is carried by the woman',
          'A man is riding a horse.',
          'A man is riding a white horse on an enclosed ground.',
          'A monkey is playing drums.',
          'Someone in a gorilla costume is playing a set of drums.',
          'A cheetah is running behind its prey.',
          'A cheetah chases prey on across a field.'
          ]
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus)

# Normalize the embeddings to unit length
corpus_embeddings = corpus_embeddings /  np.linalg.norm(corpus_embeddings, axis=1, keepdims=True)

# Perform kmean clustering
clustering_model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, distance_threshold=1.5) #, affinity='cosine', linkage='average', distance_threshold=0.4)
clustering_model.fit(corpus_embeddings)
cluster_assignment = clustering_model.labels_

clustered_sentences = {}
for sentence_id, cluster_id in enumerate(cluster_assignment):
    if cluster_id not in clustered_sentences:
        clustered_sentences[cluster_id] = []

    clustered_sentences[cluster_id].append(corpus[sentence_id])

for i, cluster in clustered_sentences.items():
    print("Cluster ", i+1)
    print(cluster)
    print("")
```

Comment: I have been working on clustering news using fast clustering, but I am unable to decide a suitable threshold for it
Can you please let me know the criteria based on which this threshold of (75%) is decided?
I will be very grateful

Answer (score 23):

You can use [Sentence Transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) to generate the sentence embeddings. These embeddings are much more meaningful as compared to the one obtained from bert-as-service, as they have been fine-tuned such that semantically similar sentences have higher similarity score. You can use FAISS based clustering algorithm if number of sentences to be clustered are in millions or more as vanilla K-means like clustering algorithm takes quadratic time.

Comment: It baffles me why so many people try to use BERT embeddings for semantic similarity. BERT was never trained for the semantic similarity objective.

Comment: Hey @jamix. Kindly note that we are not using the vanilla BERT embeddings directly here. We have modified the downstream task using siamese-like network which generates enriched sentence embeddings. Please read the the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10084

Comment: Thanks! In my comment, I'm actually agreeing with your approach. The rant was directed at the original question where vanilla BERT is being used.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to generate bert embeddidngs for the sentences first. 
bert-as-service provides a very easy way to generate embeddings for sentences.

This is how you can geberate bert vectors for a list of sentences you need to cluster. It is explained very well in the bert-as-service repository:
https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service

Installations:

```
pip install bert-serving-server  # server
pip install bert-serving-client  # client, independent of `bert-serving-server`
```

Download one of the pre-trained models available at https://github.com/google-research/bert

Start the service:

```
bert-serving-start -model_dir /your_model_directory/ -num_worker=4
```

Generate the vectors for the list of sentences:

```
from bert_serving.client import BertClient
bc = BertClient()
vectors=bc.encode(your_list_of_sentences)
```

This would give you a list of vectors, you could write them into a csv and use any clustering algorithm as the sentences are reduced to numbers.

Comment: Great solution, worked for my 42,000 hashtags

Comment: BERT is not optimized to generate sentence vectors or to assess similarity using metrics such as cosine similarity. Even though it might work, the results can be misleading. See this discussion: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/80

Comment: This is fine as long as you use a fine-tuned bert made specifically for this, eg Sentence Bert

Answer (score 3):

Bert adds a special [CLS] token at the beginning of each sample/sentence. After fine-tuning on a downstream task, the embedding of this [CLS] token or pooled_output as they call it in the hugging face implementation represents the sentence embedding.

But I think that you don't have labels so you won't be able to fine-tune, therefore you cannot use the pooled_output as a sentence embedding. Instead you should use the word embeddings in encoded_layers which is a tensor with dimensions (12,seq_len, 768). In this tensor you have the embeddings(dimension 768) from each of the 12 layers in Bert. To get the word embeddings you can use the output of the last layer, you can concatenate or sum the output of the last 4 layers and so on.

Here is the script for extracting the features: https://github.com/ethanjperez/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/examples/extract_features.py

Comment: BERT is pre-trained on a next sentence prediction task, so I would think the [CLS] token already encodes the sentence. However, I would rather go with @Palak's solution below

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need it but recently a paper mentioned how to use document embeddings to cluster documents and extract words from each cluster to represent a topic. Here's the link:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.09470.pdf, https://github.com/ddangelov/Top2Vec

Inspired by the above paper, another algorithm for topic modelling using BERT to generate sentence embeddings is mentioned here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/topic-modeling-with-bert-779f7db187e6, https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic

The above two libraries provide an end-to-end solution to extract topics from a corpus. But if you're interested only in generating sentence embeddings, look at Gensim's doc2vec (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) or at sentence-transformers (https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) as mentioned in the other answers. If you go with sentence-transformers, it is suggested that you train a model on you're domain specific corpus to get good results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this cool bertopic library - it does 1) encoding via bert or similar models 2) dimension-reduction 3) clustering
https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/index.html