# Find most similar sentence in a large dataset of sentences

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I currently have a text file with around a million sentences, each on a new line.
I am trying to build a solution where I can take a new sentence outside of this text file and have the program return the most similar sentence present in the file.

I have found some solutions which return the pair of sentences with the highest similarity INSIDE the existing dataset.For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718559/finding-most-similar-sentences-among-all-in-python) one. But that is not what I am going for. I want to be able to compare a new sentence with all of those in the text file.

Also, I am not sure if I should be focusing on semantic similarity or cosine similarity.

Comment: How do you define "most similar"?

Comment: This is similar to the problem of finding the [most similar document](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148744/finding-similar-documents-in-a-big-data-set) in a large dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to read about [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance).
I was also looking for a similar solution and settled on this algorithm.

There are implementations for Python:

- [fastDamerauLevenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/fastDamerauLevenshtein/)
- [pyxDamerauLevenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/pyxDamerauLevenshtein/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer this will is the direction I am looking for!

Comment: In very large datasets, it is not always feasible to compute the Levenshtein distance of every possible pair of sentences. There are [several other algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4640306/975097) that may be better for this purpose.